# OK, I know about the anonymity of cryptocurrency, but

Tags: transactions, trading, tracking

Normally I'd just use Browser History and things would be finished, but a little kid poured Apple Juice all over my last laptop. Thus, I have a new computer.

I bought the BTC through Coinmama.com. Apparently, I had visited another website before. At any rate, I have 0.095951 BTC in a wallet, but I do not know where it is.

Is there a website (like bitref.com or bitcoinwhoswho.com) to track the "originator" website?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a website (like bitref.com or bitcoinwhoswho.com) to track the "originator" website?

No, there is nowhere you can check something like this. You will need to remember which wallet (or service) you were using in order to claim your bitcoin.